# Remove Filter 'format_value' from Flexible Field Type In Advanced Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on some customisation of the flexible field field type. What I would like to do is remove the format_value filter altogether and an my own filter the runs after load_value

I've tried the following code to remove the filter which I was convinced would work. but alas. What am I doing wrong?

`remove_filter( 'acf/format_value/type=flexible_content', array('acf_field_flexible_content', 'format_value'), 10 );`

Reference:

Here is info on the filter:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-format_value/

in $wp_filter global here is the reference:

```
[acf/format_value/type=flexible_content] => WP_Hook Object
        (
            [callbacks] => Array
                (
                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [000000004e0e085b00000000706fba6bformat_value] => Array
                                (
                                    [function] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => acf_field_flexible_content Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => flexible_content
                                                    [label] => Flexible Content
                                                    [category] => layout
                                                    [defaults] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [layouts] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                            [min] => 
                                                            [max] => 
                                                            [button_label] => Add Row
                                                        )

                                                    [l10n] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [layout] => layout
                                                            [layouts] => layouts
                                                            [remove] => remove {layout}?
                                                            [min] => This field requires at least {min} {identifier}
                                                            [max] => This field has a limit of {max} {identifier}
                                                            [min_layout] => This field requires at least {min} {label} {identifier}
                                                            [max_layout] => Maximum {label} limit reached ({max} {identifier})
                                                            [available] => {available} {label} {identifier} available (max {max})
                                                            [required] => {required} {label} {identifier} required (min {min})
                                                            [layout_warning] => Flexible Content requires at least 1 layout
                                                        )

                                                    [public] => 1
                                                )

                                            [1] => format_value
                                        )

                                    [accepted_args] => 3
                                )

                        )

                    [4000] => Array
                        (
                            [my_acf_format_valuexxxx] => Array
                                (
                                    [function] => my_acf_format_valuexxxx
                                    [accepted_args] => 3
                                )

                        )

                )

            [iterations:WP_Hook:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [current_priority:WP_Hook:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [nesting_level:WP_Hook:private] => 0
            [doing_action:WP_Hook:private] => 
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add, that you have to use it inside `acf/init` hook. Otherwise it won't work or if you'll use `init` hook, you'll get fatal because `acf_get_field_type` is not defined.
(I used the same approach with gallery field)

```
add_action('acf/init', function () {
    remove_filter('acf/format_value/type=gallery', array(acf_get_field_type('gallery'), 'format_value'), 10);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up raising a support ticket with ACF about this and got a great response and solution FYI:

> The remove_filter function requires an objct as the first argument to the  > array target, not a string. You can get the flexible content field
>   object like so:
>
> `acf_get_field_type( $field_type )`
>
> Using this in action, your code should look like:

```
remove_filter('acf/format_value/type=flexible_content',array(acf_get_field_type('flexible_content'), 'format_value'), 10 );
```

Tested and works :-)